# Excel column data rearrange with keyword matching into rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rearrange the data in excel. For instance, I have a lot of contact details, which I have to arrange into meaningful columns

This is the original format

[image: original format]

and the desired output format is :

[image: output Format]

Since in the second contact details, I don't have the address, I can add extra empty row so that I have nothing to read in that row. But the main task will also be able to differentiate according to the keywords "Club:", "Ph:" and demarcations like "," , " " etc.

Actually I though about solving this problem using vba or some techniques in excel. But I am new to vba programming environment. I would be glad if someone can point out in the right direction to achieve my task.

Thank you

Comment: @Jonnus Thank you for editing my post. Actually I was wondering how exactly did u edit my post. Because earlier I was also trying to post the inline pictures but couldn't do it. So I did it as links

Comment: New users posts go to a list for more experienced users to review to check for suitability.  Also with more reputation you get extra privileges, like being able to insert images directly to a post.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation and http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: Easy to pick out the delimiters using, in VBA, the Split or Instr methods.  But without a known and consistent format for the address line, that will not be possible to parse, and you have not indicated the address line format.  Since SO is not a free code-writing service, please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your main question i suppose to use `split` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) and `like` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx).

By `like` operator you can check, if row contains Club: and Ph: substrings and with split you can parse your input data and store them as you need.

But beware that you need to maintain some basic data structure, so your parser wont mismatch data.

Comment: @Suk Thank you for the reply